# Ubuntu unmet dependencies sdformat error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am unable to install anything in my ubuntu 12.04 the error being shown is
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gazebo : Depends: sdformat (>= 1.4.7~) but it is not going to be installed  ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins : Depends: sdformat but it is not going to be installed
ros-hydro-gazebo-ros : Depends: sdformat but it is not going to be installed
ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control : Depends: sdformat but it is not going to be installed

Comment: You'd do better asking on [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to resolve unmet dependency in ubuntu

> `**sudo apt-get -f install**`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to uninstall any package of sdf and just install drcsim which should pull all dependendencies for you:

```
sudo apt-get remove '.*sdformat.*'
sudo apt-get install drcsim
```

All Gazebo/DRCSim related question are going to be answer faster in http://answers.gazebosim.org

Thanks.